# How to configure Django such that emails are sent by both smtp, and to a log file?

Tags: django, email, ubuntu, logging, smtp

I'm frequently plagued by the complaints that email from a django application running on its own Ubuntu LTS 16.04 server, is not being received. Typically these are the password change request emails, so they're part of the standard Django Auth module as I understand it.

Django's sendtestemail appears to work reliably, and many of the expected emails are actually sent and received (from what we can discern). The smtp setup is such that `EMAIL_HOST` is set to an smtp server on the same network that supports anonymous message relay (from servers on the same network only), and the `EMAIL_BACKEND` is the typical `django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend`. Using the console backend for testing shows that emails are triggered as we would expect on these various events.

So, what I want to be able to do, is to have **both** email sent out via the smtp relay as expected, but also be added to a log file, and for this to happen for all emails generated by all the email events in the Django app.

1. Is this possible using django configuration?
2. If not, can you recommend a method by which I can both send and log the emails?
3. Bonus query - can the solution allows me to resend an email using the original content?

Comment: 1. create your own backend (based on SmtpBackend) with added logging. 2. your SMTP server certainly has it's own logging abilities 3. I don't know. But chances are your problem come from SMTP server configuration leading to mails being classified as junk by some of the recipients.

Comment: Thank you, a valuable prompt, and one that had been hiding in a blindspot for me. A little further looking suggests there are also some third party libraries that can be plugged in as alternative email backends, but none yet that quite offer the functionality I'm looking for. However, if nothing else comes along, I'll have to see about creating or extending a backend that can solve this as it doesn't appear to already exist.